# How to set the position of the bootstrap notification icon

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Can anyone tell me the way to set the Bootstrap notification icon position

Sample code

```js
$('body').notify({  
    message: 'Hello World',  
    type: 'danger'  
});
```

My problem here is notification icon and the notification message are not aligning. see the below image.

[image]

In the above picture text and the icon are not aligning.

Comment: Please add a complete working example, with required CSS and HTML. Without that we are just guessing what's wrong here.

Comment: Please add your html css here

Comment: you can check your problem here also http://bootstrap-notify.remabledesigns.com/

Answer (score 0):

add this CSS and change top: 1px; according to your position.

```
.glyphicon {
position: relative;
top: 1px;
display: inline-block;
font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
font-style: normal;
font-weight: 400;
line-height: 1;
-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
-moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
```

}

Comment: I have the issue with exclamatory symbol icon

Comment: @RaviChanduri please check above css

Answer (score 0):

add css...and reference your warning icon and text as labeled, I labelled mine "icon" and "text"

```
.icon{
padding: 15px;
}
.text{
padding:15px;
}

Make sure they're both in the same Div
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all your answers. I have tried the provided CSS styles on the sample project.It was working on it, but when it comes to my project it won't work.

After few hours of investigation, I have found that the issue is due to the test size.
I just posted this answer to tell the cause of the issue.